# Call to service by the gateway is not found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I'm starting with spring cloud.

I created 3 application, one is for discovery service, one for gateway and one is a service.
I'm not using actually spring cloud config and any load balacing

For my **discovery**

```
server.port=8761
spring.application.name=discovery-service
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=false  
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```

For my **gateway**

```
#Port for Registry service
server.port=8080
spring.application.name=gateway-service
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=hostel-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://hostel-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/hostels/**
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

For my **hostels service**

```
server.port=9000
spring.application.name=hostel-service
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

I see then hostel service is registered in the discovery service

> Registered instance HOSTEL-SERVICE/192.168.102.129:hostel-service:9000
>   with status UP (replication=false)

See it to when i go to http://localhost:8761/

When I try to call

> http://localhost:8080/hostels
>   or
>   http://localhost:8080/hostel-service/hostels

I get a 404 error

If I do

> http://localhost:9000/hostels

I get good results

Edit

Code on github

https://github.com/mctdi/hostel
https://github.com/mctdi/gateway
https://github.com/mctdi/discovery

Comment: gateway needs `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8061/eureka/`

Comment: calls to eureka (port 8061) will never proxy anything

Comment: same error with eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone key   https://piotrminkowski.wordpress.com/2018/04/26/quick-guide-to-microservices-with-spring-boot-2-0-eureka-and-spring-cloud/ say the opposite about the call

Comment: but proxying will only work on port 8080. You're saying that doesn't work? (since you changed your question)

Comment: ya same result on 8080

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hostels` app registers in Service Discovery, but the `gateway` app doesn't. Add `'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'` to you `implementation` dependencies in `build.gradle` - it will then register in Eureka and the `http://localhost:8080/hostels` request will be routed to the `hostels` app.

Comment: that worked but i was thinking that will work with this url: http://localhost:8080/hostel-service/hostels but needed to use http://localhost:8080/hostels

Comment: It determines what enters the route using the `path` predicate, and then passes whatever was matched via load balancer using the provided service id after lb://. You do not have a route defined with path predicate starting with `/hostel-service/hostels`.